# attach a panel to TreeView control

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, panel

I am beginner in c#. In my project, I populated a xml file inside a TreeView control. If the xml file is large, the `TreeView` control is showing the data with scroll bars. Beside this, whenever the user double clicks a node I am showing a panel beside the selected node something like this..

[image]

*When I scroll the TreeView Control* :

[image]

My question is how to make the `panel` attached to `treeView` control so that eventhough the user scrolls the `TreeView` control the panel should also move along with the selected node.

Comment: Is this an html application or a winforms application?

Comment: WinForms..sorry i always forget to keep the tag

Comment: How r u showing that panel in front of selected Node ??

Comment: I think that is not necessary because it is not related to the problem anyway this is the code: `myPanel.SetBounds(myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.X + 50, myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Y, myPanel.Width, myPanel.Height);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, hard to do since TreeView doesn't have a Scroll event.  It isn't reliable anyway since nodes can be expanded and collapsed, changing the position and visibility of the node.  The backup plan is to use a Timer.  This worked well:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        if (node == null || !node.IsVisible) panel1.Visible = false;
        else {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            var nodepos = treeView1.PointToScreen(node.Bounds.Location);
            var panelpos = panel1.Parent.PointToClient(nodepos);
            panel1.Top = panelpos.Y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was about to post this link, http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/. But this should get the job done without any complexity.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work. I pasted your code as it is.. should I make any changes in it? (not the control names, I added timer control also)

Comment: This is tested code.  Did you forget to enable the timer?  Did you subscribe the Tick event?  Did you change the control names?