# Find width of a tree node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I need to find out the width of a selected node in a treeView control.

The text to the node is being added through button click and sometimes the text is large inside the node then it messing up all the design of my form. I tried so much but I cant find any properties existing which can find the width of a node (may be there can be). If it is a silly question give the answer in comment, so that I can delete the question later.

Please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 1) What is wrong with design? Horizontal scroll-bar? 2) What do you want to do with text? Change font? Ellepsis?

Comment: @Orsol It is a [**big code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13091200/1577396), I cant post here. I will try to explain it "I am showing some panel beside the selected node, when the text is large, the panel hiding the text". Hope you understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about calling `Graphics.MeasureString`?  Should get you close enough to actual width.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx#Y0

Comment: You will need to know left indent of node

Comment: that is no problem for me It can be done using `myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.X`

Comment: If myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Width doesn't suite your needs then I think you'll not find better answer.

Comment: This is working. Should have checked it. This concept is new to me. I knew this through SO itself.